# What impact could it have to set acpi=off during Ubuntu installation?

Tags: ubuntu, installation, acpi

I've had a hard time getting Ubuntu installed on my Acer laptop.

[This guy](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1140101) recommended setting acpi=off to workaround some of the boot issues.

If this solution is successful in getting Ubuntu to boot up, could it have an impact on the performance/functionality of the OS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting ACPI off means that Ubuntu will not attempt to use [ACPI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Configuration_and_Power_Interface) features like Power Saving, Standby, Hibernate amongst others.